# Pass two id's in find query to update status database in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel-4

public function index($establishment_id,$subcat_id)
    {

```
    EstablishmnetSubcategories::find($establishment_id)->update('status',1);

    echo "success";
}
```

This is my controller code, i want to update a column value with status = 1, but i have to verify with two id's if it matches then only it should get update.
i am not getting how to pass two id's in find query.
Can anyone please help me ..thank you

Comment: use `where clause` instead of `find`

Comment: public function index($establishment_id,$subcat_id)
 {
  
$est = EstablishmnetSubcategories::where('establishment_id','=',$establishment_id)->where('subcategory_id','=',$subcat_id);
  
  $est->status=1;
  
  
  echo "sucess";
 }                                                                                                                  I updated my code like this, but its not updating, please check it once..thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
EstablishmentSubcategories::where('establishment_id', $establishment_id)
    ->where('subcategory_id', $subcat_id)
    ->update(['status' => 1]); // add update on update query in your query no where update

echo "success";
```

Comment: Sorry, but its not updating with that query, is any other  query available to update it...thank you

Comment: $est = EstablishmnetSubcategories::where('establishment_id','=',$establishment_id)->where('subcategory_id','=',$subcat_id);
  
  $input['status'] = 1;
  
  $est->update($input);                                                                                       got it, its working with this code...thank you